# extending tsconfig seems to be getting ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a tsconfig in the root of my app which gets created by `create-react-app`. With in the src folder of my app, I have a folder called api which is where I have nodejs server side code. The problem I have, is that the tsconfig of `create-react-app` does not work for what I need in my server side code.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "downlevelIteration":true,
    "baseUrl": "src/",
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "api"
  ]
}
```

The problem is with the `"module": "esnext",` This option only works for client side code, but wont work for node unless if I have .mjs extension if I understand correctly. In node I need this option set to commonjs. This is causing me to get the following error when running my code

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

So I attempted to create a new tsconfig file inside the api folder which extends the tsconfig of the root of the app. Here is that code.

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
  }
}
```

It feels like this is getting totally ignored however, because I am still getting the exact same error.

EDIT: I added an option to exclude the api folder in my root tsconfig. Still not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first thought is that you should potentially make the global tsconfig "exclude": [] your api directory.  That way when it executes, it will skip that folder.

Comment: is this in addition to what I have? Or should I just try this alone?

Comment: In addition. I *believe* that even though you have two different tsconfg files, the first one is not going to be ignored.  It is still going to try to do it's logic against the files it matches, which includes your app folder.  It should then later also do its logic using the nested config file.  That is my (limited) understanding.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will give this a shot

Answer (score 0):

While this does not answer my question directly, I did manage to solve my issue by giving `ts-node` the exact path of the tsconfig I want it to use when running the server side code. Here is what that looks like.

`"start:server": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --compiler typescript --project src/api/tsconfig.api.json src/api/index_server.ts"`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well and this post helped me a long way along the line but I had to do some things different.

Our issue is that our client app needs `"module": "ESNext"`, to package things. My homie dev said that using `"module": "CommonJS"` used full libraries thus creating build folder x4 mb compared to using ESNext.

We looked at workspace and extending but I got the feeling that the new tsconfig was ignored leading me to this post.

```
./client-app
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
│
└── ./src
    ├── ./hooks, components, routes etc
    └── ./tests
        └── tsconfig.commonjs.json // child tsconfig
```

This is how I solved it (npm run automation)
"automation": "ts-node --project src/tests/tsconfig.commonjs.json ./node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js src/tests/features/**/*.feature --require-module ts-node/register --require src/tests/test.setup.ts --require src/tests/step-definitions/**/*.spec.ts",

--project tells node to explicitly specify the path to a tsconfig.json. The rest is the exact path cucumber followed by path settings for my feature and step-definition files.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    **"module": "ESNext",**
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tests", "static"]
}
```

tsconfig.commonjs.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS"
  }
}
```

I hope that this helps someone in the future.